# Merging rows in datatable slow on large datasets in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a datatable with stats data from a cassandra database.

It is often a lot of rows (in the area of 20k-45k rows).

The rows are divided into hours and I need to merge them into days.

The code i have now only takes around 1-3ms to process a row but if there is 45k rows or more it still takes quite a while..

So I would like to know if there is a better way of doing it
Any ideas would be hugely appreciated!

Current code

```
public static DataTable CollateResult(DataTable table)
    {
        DataTable m_table = table.Copy();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            string m_date = DateTime.Parse(row["event_time"].ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            if (m_table.Rows.Count > 0 && m_table.Rows[m_table.Rows.Count - 1]["event_time"].ToString().Equals(m_date))
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    if (!column.ColumnName.Equals("event_time") && !column.ColumnName.Equals("application_id") && !column.ColumnName.Equals("country") && !column.ColumnName.Equals("package"))
                    {
                        m_table.Rows[m_table.Rows.Count - 1][column.ColumnName] =
                            (int.Parse(m_table.Rows[m_table.Rows.Count - 1][column.ColumnName].ToString()) + int.Parse(row[column.ColumnName].ToString()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!column.ColumnName.Equals("event_time"))
                            m_table.Rows[m_table.Rows.Count - 1][column.ColumnName] = row[column.ColumnName].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DataRow m_row = m_table.NewRow();
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    if (column.ColumnName.Equals("event_time"))
                        m_row["event_time"] = m_date;
                    else
                        m_row[column.ColumnName] = row[column.ColumnName];
                }
                m_table.Rows.Add(m_row);
            }
        }
        return m_table;
    }
```

Comment: You don't "merge" into days, you "aggregate". There is a *huge* difference. Aggregate means you use aggregate functions like Sum, Avg, Count and groupings. Instead of treating the data table as a 2D array and iterating, use filters and aggregates to filter the rows you want, group them by days then sum the values you need. Better yet, do that in SQL. The corresponding SQL statement is very easy and will probably run  faster

Comment: @mybirthname I'm not sure about this. The code is *very* convoluted and displays unfamiliarity with DataTables. It would be passed right back to SO

Comment: @n-dev Just explain what you want to do, not how you think it should be done. You want to filter by what field, group by which columns and generate what sums?

Comment: There is a lot of repetition, not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: i knew i probably had it wrong!

i have an event_time column with the date in a format i can choose myself

event_time, country, application_id and package are columns i would like to group on so i would have 1 row per day,country, application_id, package

all other columns in the table are counter values from cassandra that needs to be added together into a daily value

in sql i would use a group by statement but cassandra doesnt seem to support that

Answer (score 0):

Ok I decided to look into linq since that has the "sql" functions i needed..
So this ended up being the solution to my problem:

```
        List<StatsResult> m_results =
                (
                  from row in m_table.AsEnumerable()
                  group row by new {
                      EventTime = row.Field<string>("event_time"),
                      Package = row.Field<string>("package"),
                      Name = row.Field<string>("name"),
                      Country = row.Field<string>("country")
                  } into g
                  select new StatsResult()
                  {
                      event_time = g.Key.EventTime,
                      package = g.Key.Package,
                      name = g.Key.Name,
                      country = g.Key.Country,
                      ActiveUsers = g.Sum(x => x.Field<long>("ActiveUsers")),
                      MonthlyActiveUsers = g.Sum(x => x.Field<long>("MonthlyActiveUsers"))
                  }
                ).ToList();
```